# How can I get insert query to work with two if(isset statements?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, isset

On a users profile, there is a comment box that enables other users to post comments on their profile. I am now working on a dynamic comment area that has a changing text box depending on if A. you are looking at your own profile B. looking at someone elses profile C. not signed in at all.

I am trying to implement "updates" now when you are on your own page, type in the comment box, and it outputs in a designated area on your page.  ( going to have it output on a community page but not there yet)

On this profile page, I have the insert query that is inserting regular comments just fine (the first insert query) and now am trying to add a second if(isset statement with a second insert query and am having trouble doing this.

It is not inserting and the page is loading blank after the submit button is hit. I am a newbie with php btw. Thank you:

```
    /* code chunk for the regular comments that is working just fine */

       if(isset($_POST['commentProfileSubmit']) && $auth) {

       $query = "SELECT `Email` FROM `Users` WHERE `id` = '" . $prof->id . "'";
       $request = mysql_query($query,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
       $result = mysql_fetch_array($request); 

       $Email = $result['Email'];


       $to = $Email;
       $subject = "$auth->first_name $auth->last_name left you a comment";
       $message = "$auth->first_name $auth->last_name left you a comment: <br /><br /> <a href='http://www.blah.org/Profile.php?id=" . $prof->id . "'>Click here to view</a><br /><br />";
       $from = "blah <noreply@blah.org>";
       $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
       $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
       $headers .= "From: $from";
       mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);



        $query = "INSERT INTO `ProfileComments` 
                                ( `FromUserID`,
                                  `ToUserID`,
                                  `commentProfileBody`,
                                  `status`,
                                  `date`,
                                  `time`

                                    ) VALUES (

                                '" . $auth->id ."',
                                '" . $prof->id ."',
                                              '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ProfileComment']) ."',
                                 'active',
                                '" . date("Y-m-d") . "',
                                '" . date("G:i:s") . "')";

    mysql_query($query,$connection); 

     /* code chunk that is not inserting the desired info into the db and loading the page blank when I hit submit */

      }elseif(isset($_POST['airwaveSubmit']) && $auth) {

      $query2 = "INSERT INTO `Airwaves`
                            ( `id`,
                             `body`,
                             `status`,
                             `date`,
                             `time`

                            ) VALUES (

                            '" . $auth->id ."',
                            '" . $mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['body']) . "',
                            'active',
                            '" . date("Y-m-d") . "',
                            '" . date("G:i:s") . "')";

                                            mysql_query($query,$connection);    

            }
         ?> 

    /* dynamic text/areas with dynamic submit buttons which is working how it should but want to include in case there is something on here that is causing the previous troubles */

<div id="commentBoxBlog">
<form name="CommentBox" method="post" action="Profile2.php?id=<?php echo $prof->id; ?>">
    <?php if($auth->id == $prof->id) {
    echo    "<div id='counter'>
    <span id='counter_airway'>140 Character Limit</span>
    </div>";
    echo "<textarea name='airwaveBody' class='round_10px' onkeyup='limit_length(this,140,\"counter_airway\");'></textarea>  <input type='submit' name='airwaveSubmit' value='Exhale' class='post'/>";} elseif(!$auth) {
 echo "<textarea name='ProfileComment' class='round_10px' disabled>Please sign in to comment...</textarea>";  } elseif($auth->id != $prof->id) 
  echo "<textarea name='ProfileComment' class='round_10px'></textarea>
    <input type='submit' name='commentProfileSubmit' value='Exhale' class='post' />";

    ?>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there anything in the php error log?

Comment: error log is turned off. Being a newbie I have some loose ends that are not compromising the functionality of my site, but have alot of users and it would show stuff that would make the site look broken, error display wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the SQL in a variable named $query2, but in your mysql_query() call to send it to the database you use a variable named $query.

Comment: still is loading the page blank and not inserting. That is good to know though. Thanks